# Раскрывающийся view элемент

Tags: android, android-sdk

Всем привет. Необходимо реализовать view элемент, который раскрывается при нажатии. Пример реализован в приложении часы в Android (см. скриншоты). Подскажите, в какую сторону гуглить, или может есть стандартные реализации. ExpandableTextView смотрел, но, мне кажется, это не совсем то, что мне нужно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Любой `View` имеет параметр видимости (в XML - `android:visibility` или в коде метод `setVisibility()`). Для элементов, которые не должны отображаться в "скрытом" состоянии назначаете его `View.GONE`. Когда нужно "раскрыть" - устанавливаете для них `View.VISIBLE` и все.

Comment: @pavlofff но тут не только видимость, так же идет смещение остальных view вниз

Comment: Здесь `ListView` (`RecyclerView`), каждый будильник - айтем в нем. Когда вы измените видимость элементов в айтеме, все само сместиться как надо после обновления адаптера списка.

Comment: @pavloff не знал, пойду пробывать. Если это так - огромное спасибо! Долго мучался)

Comment: @pavlofff да, все работает. Только я не в RecyclerView это делаю, а просто во фрагменте. И такой вопрос, как можно добиться плавности открытия невидимого поля? Есть ли стандартное поведение для этого, или надо писать самому? Использую CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score 1):

В основе этого экрана - список `ListView` или `RecyclerView`/ Адаптер этого списка должен отображать два типа айтемов - раскрытый и сжатый. В данных для адаптера должно быть поле, определяющее состояние каждого айтема (раскрыт он или скрыт).
Метод `getView()` адаптера читает это поле и устанавливает соостветствующую видимость для отображения методом `setVisiblity()` для вложенных в айтем элементов.

При нажатии на кнопку раскрытия\скрытия в данные записывается соответствующее состояние и адаптер обновляется для перерисовки нового вида.

`RecyclerView` позволяет использовать анимации этого процесса через метод [`notifyItemChanged()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int))