# Раскрывающиеся элементы списка RecyclerView в Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.android

Надеюсь вопрос не слишком сложно написан :D

Как такое [Раскрывающийся view элемент](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/551567/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F-view-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82) реализовать?

Суть(вдруг по ссылке не переходили или не понял) в том, чтобы при нажатии на элемент списка, этот элемент расширялся = отображалась его ранее невидимая часть или дополнялась. Нажал = внизу отобразилась доп. информации а остальные элементы списка сдвинулись вниз, освобождая место.

Пробовал по документации https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/recycler-view/extending-the-example:

Пробовал в

```
public override void
        OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder _holder, int position)
```

добавлять к элементу обработчик нажатия:

```
holder.PavilionNum.Click -= (sender, e) => OnClick(holder.AdapterPosition);
holder.PavilionNum.Click += (sender, e) => OnClick(holder.AdapterPosition);
```

пробовал в методах

```
public override void OnViewAttachedToWindow(Java.Lang.Object _holder)
public override void OnViewDetachedFromWindow(Java.Lang.Object _holder)
```

добавлять обработчик нажатия и удалять его, в "OnCreate" пробовал.

Но всегда прога работала не так: поведение списка было непредсказуемым. Но по логике этой же "неправильной работы" О_о, ошибка находится в способе добавления обработчика нажатия или в его реализации.
Можете подсказать правильную реализацию? Желательно код реализации RecyclerView или ссылку на github

Comment: Такая вещь называется `Expander`, я не знаю как у вас там в Xamarin, но уверен, что есть контрол уже готовый с этим функционалом. Если же нет, то ищите, Xamarin часто дописывают сами пользователи, увы... Например вот [первое попавшееся в гугле](https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/ExpandableView).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Такой элемент есть, но я думал что он только для реализации "списка в списке"